# Can apache cayenne support reactive streams libraries similar to Hibernate Reactive

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, apache-cayenne

Can apache cayenne support reactive streams libraries similar to Hibernate Reactive

I didn't find any information about this topic. currently were using typical cayenne orm using typical jdbc driver. we want to use spring web-flux and our underlaying ORM is apache cayenne

Answer (score 0):

There are no special reactive APIs around Cayenne. Though it won't be that hard to invoke ObjectContext from a reactive stack. The underlying framework will still be blocking (so is Hibernate's if I understand correctly). After all JDBC is blocking. But you can call it in a non-blocking fashion.

FWIW, I did the above successfully with Java CompletableFutures (the "native" reactive stack in Java).